# Custom image upload attribute for category not working in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: upgrade, image-upload, category-attribute, magento2.2.3

I have upgraded magento 2.1.7 to 2.2.3.

I have some custom image attribute in category. It was working fine in magento 2.1.7 but not working in upgraded magento 2.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create module using below code:

create **registration.php** file at **app/code/Prashant/CustomImage/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Prashant_CustomImage',
    __DIR__
);
```

create **module.xml** file at **app/code/Prashant/CustomImage/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Prashant_CustomImage" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

create **routes.xml** file at **app/code/Prashant/CustomImage/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="admin">
            <route id="customimage" frontName="customimage">
                <module name="Prashant_CustomImage" before="Magento_Backend" />
            </route>
        </router>
    </config>
```

Create a **InstallData.php** file at **app/code/Prashant/CustomImage/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Prashant\CustomImage\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory.
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $_eavSetupFactory;
    protected $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init.
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $setup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);         
        $setup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'custom_image', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 9,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Create **category_form.xml** file at **app/code/Prashant/CustomImage/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="custom_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customimage/category_image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

create **di.xml** file at in **app/code/Prashant/CustomImage/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<type name="Prashant\CustomImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider" type="Prashant\CustomImage\Model\Category\DataProvider" />
```

Create **Upload.php** controller file at **app/code/Prashant/CustomImage/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image/Upload.php**

```
<?php
namespace Prashant\CustomImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Category Image Upload Controller
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Uploader factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * Media directory object (writable).
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * Core file storage database
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Upload constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Prashant_CustomImage::category');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $imageId = $this->_request->getParam('param_name', 'custom_image');

        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($imageId);

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

create **DataProvider.php** file at **app/code/Prashant/CustomImage/Model/Category/DataProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace Prashant\CustomImage\Model\Category;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider
{

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $fileInfo;

    public function getData()
    {
        $data = parent::getData();
        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($category) {
            $categoryData = $category->getData();
            $categoryData = $this->addUseConfigSettings($categoryData);
            $categoryData = $this->filterFields($categoryData);
            $categoryData = $this->convertValues($category, $categoryData);

            $this->loadedData[$category->getId()] = $categoryData;
        }

        if (isset($data['custom_image'])) {
            unset($data['custom_image']);

            //create getCategoryThumbUrl in helper file
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $helper     = $objectManager->get('\[ Vendor ]\[ Module ]\Helper\Data');

            $data[$category->getId()]['custom_image'][0]['name'] = $category->getData('custom_image');
            $data[$category->getId()]['custom_image'][0]['url']  = $helper->getCategoryThumbUrl($category);
            $data[$category->getId()]['custom_image'][0]['size'] = isset($stat) ? $stat['size'] : 0;
            $data[$category->getId()]['custom_image'][0]['type'] = $mime;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    protected function getFieldsMap()
    {
        $fields = parent::getFieldsMap();
        $fields['content'][] = 'custom_image'; // custom image field

        return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Get FileInfo instance
     *
     * @return FileInfo
     *
     * @deprecated 101.1.0
     */
    private function getFileInfo()
    {
        if ($this->fileInfo === null) {
            $this->fileInfo = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(FileInfo::class);
        }
        return $this->fileInfo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager->get('\[ Vendor ]\[ Module ]\Helper\Data');
```

Wants a helper file can you please check this ?