# M2.3 - Adding custom category image removes default thumbnail

Tags: magento2.3, custom, category-attribute

I've used [this module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219753/37536) to add an extra category image field to my categories. The field itself is working fine, but whenever I add an image to it, it removes the default Category Image. When I go to add that back in, it removes my custom image again. Why is that?

I've found that adding both images at the same time and then saving does work, but I don't want to rely on my clients to do this everytime..

Comment: You mean you want to set custom image instead of default place holder image?

Comment: No I want both: I want the default Category Image field PLUS a custom, extra image field.